# Como comparar uma frase inserida com as existentes na BD devolvendo a probabilidade de serem semelhantes?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Gostaria de saber como comparar uma frase inserida pelo utilizador com as existentes na BD de forma a devolver a probabilidade de serem semelhantes. tenho um código semelhante que compara duas *strings* em JAVA mas precisava de o fazer em PHP+MySQL

Answer (score 3):

A função strcasecmp compara duas strings sem diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas.

```
$var1 = 'A';
$var2 = 'a';

//comparacao case insensitive
if(strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {

    echo $var1.' (igual) '.$var2; //Imprime 'A igual a'
}
```

A função strcmp compara duas strings diferenciando maiúsculas e minúsculas.

```
//comparacao case sensitive
if(strcmp($var1, $var2) != 0) {

    echo $var1.' (diferente) '.$var2; //Imprime 'A diferente de a'
}

$var1 = 'A';
$var2 = 'B';

//comparacao case sensitive
if(strcmp($var1, $var2) != 0) {

    echo $var1.' (diferente) '.$var2; //Imprime 'A diferente de B
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Existe a função [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.similar-text.php), ela calcula a similaridade entre duas strings, por exemplo:

```
similar_text('Olá mundo', 'Oi Mundo', $percentualSimilaridade);
echo 'Percentual de similaridade: ' . $percentualSimilaridade; // Imprime 66.6666666667
```

Ou seja, as duas frases tem aproximadamente 66.67% de similaridade.

Comment: http://androidaddicted.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/jaro-winkler-sql-code/     A jaro winkler funciona bem no Oracle

Comment: o objectivo é comparar a frase inserida com as que já estão na base de dados e retornar a similaridade. Tem ideia de como posso desenvolver o codigo?

Comment: @rockie, Acredito que você precisará preparar uma query que compare a nova frase com todas as que já existem no banco, no final ela deve retornar a maior similaridade. No Postgres eu sei de algumas maneiras de se fazer isso, mas como trabalhei muito pouco com MySQL, nele não conheço as funções nativas.