# Comparando datas de um array no PHP

Tags: php, data, if

Estou tentando comparar as datas que vem de um array do banco de dados para poder organiza-las dentro de um cronograma. O problema é que não consigo comparar as datas para saber onde colocar cada entrada...

Talvez o problema seja que dentro do array as datas estejam em formato date, mas se for isso, como comparar?

Segue o código:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><center>Manhã</center></td>
                <?php 
                    foreach($periodo as $data){
                        while ($arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())){
                            if ($arrayBancas['data'] == $data->format("Y-m-d")){
                                echo '<td>teste</td>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?> 
     </tr>
```

Conteúdo das variáveis:

(Periodo)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();} 

$idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

$oSemestre = new semestresclass();
$oSemestre -> listarEdicao($idSemestre);  

$array = mysql_fetch_array($oSemestre->retorno());

$start_date = $array['DataDeInicio'];
$end_date = $array['DataDeTermino'];

$inicio = new DateTime($start_date);
$fim = new DateTime($end_date);
$fim->modify('+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, $interval ,$fim);
```

(Array das Bancas)

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  

$idSemestre = $_SESSION['SemestreGeral'];

$oBanca = new bancasclass();
$oBanca -> listar ($idSemestre);   

$arrayBancas = mysql_fetch_array($oBanca->retorno())
```

Segue o valor das do var_export das variaiveis:

arrayBancas:
array ( 0 => '1', 'idB' => '1', 1 => NULL, 'data' => NULL, 2 => NULL, 'hora' => NULL, 3 => '316', 'sala' => '316', )

data:
DateTime::__set_state(array( 'date' => '2014-06-10 00:00:00', 'timezone_type' => 3, 'timezone' => 'GMT', ))

Comment: Você precisa organiza-las como?

Comment: Por dias e turnos. No caso, dentro desse $arrayBancas aí tenho tipo 'entradas de uma agenda' com horário, data e local... 

Aí agora tá o problema, eu to tentando começar por descobrir qual a data de cada entrada, depois provavelmente vou ter que comparar o horário de cada entrada com qual turno se encaixa e aí jogar na tela...

Comment: Tenta organizar melhor sua query para os dados virem em um formato que facilite a lógica

Comment: Olha se isso te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39631/como-comparar-uma-frase-inserida-com-as-existentes-na-bd-devolvendo-a-probabilid/39639#39639

Comment: Não, não era isso... Eu precisava comparar date com string... Como daria pra fazer?

Comment: No banco de dados a data esta armazenada como string? Ou esta como date?

Comment: No banco ela tá como Date

Comment: é estranho que isso `if ($arrayBancas['data'] == strtotime('2014-06-05')){                                   echo '<td>teste</td>';}` também não funciona...

Comment: Poste o conteúdo de **$periodo** e **$arrayBancas** usando [var_export()](http://www.php.net/var_export).

Comment: Acrescentei os códigos de cada uma delas ali na pergunta pra ficar melhor de entender

Comment: Isso não ajuda pois termos as variáveis sem termos o que elas representam impossibilita que qualquer teste seja feito. Pelo código nós até podemos fazer uma Engenharia Reversa mental e sabemos que **$array** tem dois índices chamados **DataDeInicio** e **DataDeTermino**. Mas e daí? Se, por exemplo, precisarmos saber o tamanho dos arrays para bolar uma solução não teríamos como pois pode ser apenas esses dois como podem ser mais. Repito, faça um var_export() das variáveis **$array** e **$arrayBancas** e edite a pergunta novamente.

Comment: Agora entendi! Não conhecia essa função, muito boa! Coloquei ali os valores, pelo q da pra ver a data tá null, isso que pode tá impedindo a comparação né?

Comment: Mas o estranho é que se eu percorrer o array dando um echo no array na posição da data ele imprime as datas certinho... E agora?

Comment: Ótimo. Eu imagino que esse **$arrayBancas** não deveria retornar esse tanto de valor nulo, sendo assim, você precisa consertar essa sua query para que ela retorne dados trabalháveis. Nesse meio tempo, convém também você fazer um var_dump() para ver se **$array**, **$inicio**, **$fim** e **$periodo** e ver se os objetos estão sendo preenchidos com aquilo que se espera. Consertado isso você pode usar a resposta que vou deixar abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com as recentes edições você tem dois problemas:

1. Sua query não está retornando aquilo que se espera
2. Você está comparando strings esperando obter noções de tempo

O primeiro problema só você pode resolver pois fugiria muito do escopo do tópico (mas isso não o impede de criar outro caso tenha dificuldades).

O segundo problema é bem simples de resolver, mas requer que você conserte sua estrutura no banco de dados.

Pelo *output* de **$arrayBancas** você aparenta ter um campo do tipo DATETIME mas não tem as horas. Ou você conserta a forma como insere os dados, para que as horas cheguem ou altera o tipo do campo.

Objetos DateTime são comparáveis com operadores convencionais (<, >, == e !==) então uma vez corrigido o problema anterior, basta criar um objeto DateTime com o operando do lado esquerdo e efetuar a comparação:

```
if( DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d', $arrayBancas['data'] ) -> format( 'Y-m-d' ) == $data -> format( 'Y-m-d' ) ) {
    echo '<td>teste</td>';
}
```

Caso você opte por consertar a forma como insere os dados e passar a ter as horas você troca o formato de **Y-m-d** por **Y-m-d H:i:s**.

Lembrando que o método [DateTme::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) foi introduzido no PHP 5.3.

Comment: Tá, dei uma revisada geral, aqueles NULL estavam ali por causa de uns testes que eu fiz e esqueci de apagar mesmo, agora já regularizei! Vou substituir ali na pergunta os var_export pelos do var_dump pra vc dar uma olhada! Achei curioso que aparece tudo como string

Comment: Tentei agora transformar esses valores do array com o strtotime mas não rolou...

Comment: O var_dump() foi só uma dica pra te ajudar numa possível depuração. Eu reverti as mudanças não só porque var_dump() não ajuda muito quando postado mas também porque senão o texto que eu escrevi ficaria sem sentido. Agora que eu vi como está, você pode remover a coluna **hora** e mudar o tipo do campo **data** de DATE para DATETIME, unindo os dois. E você não vai usar strtotime(), vai criar um objeto DateTime a partir do formato que a data/hora está no banco, como eud isse na resposta.

Comment: Tá, entendi, fiz isso. Agora ao invés de eu ter um campo DATE e um TIME eu tenho só o DATETIME. Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que agora aquela variável $data que eu uso pra andar entre os dois períodos não tá guardando a hora... Só a data... Como eu poderia alterar a $data para percorrer pelas horas também?

Comment: A DatePeriod trabalha com períodos de tempo. O período **P1D** definido produzirá um intervalo de datas. Você pode até formatá-lo como horas, mas não resultar no que se espera. Se você quiser o intervalo de horas de um dia pro outro, o período deve ser **PT1H**. Já se quiser uma hora por dia, **P1DT1H**. E por aí vai. Talvez se você mostrar o que você espera ter como saída fica mais fácil montar o período.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta pra ficar ainda mais evidente.

Comment: Rolou!! Finalmente!! Não consegui fazer o DateTime::createFromFormat, meu PHP aqui é o 5.5 mas não acontece nada com ele, então fiz o seguinte:
if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayBancas['dataHora'])) == $data->format('Y-m-d')) { echo 'vai'; } e finalmente rolou!! Valeu velho, muito obrigado!!!!!! Agora vou tentar continuar, se eu trancar de novo abro uma nova pergunta!! Valeu!!